# Adding a button to the title bar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, windows-7, qt4

I am writing a C++ application using Qt4 and looking to implement a GUI similar to Firefox 4. That is, I need to remove the default context menu in the top left corner of the window and replace it with three buttons. If you notice the button in Firefox 4 is right at the top in the title bar and I am uncertain as to how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be easy and will not be cross-platform. Read this [thread](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/3331/) in the qt forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the behaviour described by implementing a tool bar. More information can be found at [QT documentation on QToolBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtoolbar.html#details)